# Unable to start the Microsoft Visual Studio Debug Console

Tags: .net, visual-studio

[Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1s4nY.png)

Happened when I used .Net 7.0 instead of .Net 4.8. Even without starting debug mode in new project.

Enabled option "Automatically close the the console when debugging stops". Didn't help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Had to go to Visual Studio installer and delete my Visual Studio Community 2022 and then again install it or click on extra then restore Visual Studio Community 2022 in Visual Studio installer.